# Sonar Quebe failed due to FileUploadException

Tags: sonarqube

Sonar scanner is throwing below error :

```
2017.07.12 23:37:25 ERROR web[AV038Xu+dJJols1/AAAO][o.s.s.w.WebServiceEngine] Fail to process request http://localhost:9000/api/ce/submit?projectKey=superprojectkey&projectName=Superproject
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't read file part

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket

Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket

Caused by: java.io. 

l.findNextItem(FileUploadBase.java:874)
```

Comment: Yes I tried 2-3 times , still same issue

Comment: @janos , it worked on subsequent run . thanks!

Comment: So.... How fragile is it? What is the success rate out of let's say 5 trials?